# Can I delete `wp-config-sample.php` after installing and configuring Wordpress?

Tags: wp-config, filesystem, wp-filesystem

Can I remove `wp-config-sample.php` after installing and configuring Wordpress?

Could this have any consequences in the future?

Is this file restored after updating?

At first glance, it just seems unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can safely delete that file. It's a template of what a minimal `wp-config.php` looks like, so as soon as you have a working wp-config, you don't need it.

It will never be restored unless you reinstall Wordpress from scratch, e.g. by downloading and unpacking a clean Wordpress installation.

If for some reason you need to refer to it in the future, then you can easily get it again by downloading Wordpress and pulling it out of the archive, although it's highly likely that you'll only need it for a new manual Wordpress install.